# C# Loop limited to 50 passes

Tags: c#, loops

How do I limit the loop below to 50 so it stops when it reaches the 51st item?

```
foreach (ListViewItem lvi in listView.Items)
{

}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
foreach (ListViewItem lvi in listView.Items) {
  // do code here
  if (listView.Items.IndexOf(lvi) == 49)
    break;
}
```

OR since it is a list view item

```
foreach (ListViewItem lvi in listView.Items) {
  // do code here
  if (lvi.Index == 49) break;
}
```

Using Linq as Per [LukeDuff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/539075/c-loop-limited-to-50-passes/539152#539152)

```
foreach (ListViewItem lvi in listView.Items.Take(50)) {
  // do code here
}
```

Using For Loop as Per [Atomiton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/539075/c-loop-limited-to-50-passes/539089#539089)

```
// loop through collection to a max of 50 or the number of items
for(int i = 0; i < listView.Items.Count && i < 50; i++){
    listView.Items[i]; //access the current item

}
```

Comment: s/=/==/ and it might be off by one. But you got the break correct.

Comment: i added the //do code here so it will exit at the end of processing the 50th record to clarify :)

Comment: this is not nearly as nice as using Linq to Objects... see @LukeDuff's answer below

Comment: @smiller - not as neat, but functional to spec :) @Jade M - NP

Comment: Checking listView.Items.IndexOf(lvi) on every iteration is very expensive relative to maintaining an independent counter. The LINQ to objects Take(50) method is the quickest way, if your key criterion is just to get 50 items.

Comment: Or if you need a counter, search this site for ForEach with Index - again, there's a really neat way of doing this with extension methods which is much faster than IndexOf.

Comment: which is why i included the other two entries along with the primary answer to keep the answer up to date with the best information.

Comment: Thanks for updating your post with the different solutions!

Comment: np, they are obviously very recommended, and since the poster marked this as the answer, i figured i would toss them in for wiki reference purposes :)

Comment: Your last solution only works if the object being iterated has an indexer property - IEnumerable for example has no such indexer. Just something to keep in mind.

Answer (score 23):

Easy with Linq

```
foreach (ListViewItem lvi in listView.Items.Take(50)) {

}
```

From the MSDN documentation:

> Take<(Of <(TSource>)>) enumerates
>   source and yields elements until count
>   elements have been yielded or source
>   contains no more elements.
>
> If count is less than or equal to
>   zero, source is not enumerated and an
>   empty IEnumerable<(Of <(T>)>) is
>   returned.

Answer (score 16):

Well, the foreach may not be the best solution, but if you must:

```
int ctr = 0;
foreach (ListViewItem lvi in listView.Items) {
    ctr++;
    if (ctr == 50) break;

    // do code here

}
```

**Note: a for loop is generally lighter than using a foreach to go through a collection.**

Better to use a for loop:

```
// loop through collection to a max of 50 or the number of items
for(int i = 0; i < listView.Items.Count && i < 50; i++){
    listView.Items[i]; //access the current item

}
```

Comment: This will fail if the collection doesn't have 50 items though.

Comment: The for loop you have there will fail unless the the list happens to have 50 items - either it will iterate past the end if there are less than 50 items, or it will iterate past the 50 items if there are more.

Comment: That's what the second condition is for in the for loop (|| i < listView.Items.Count;).  In the foreach loop, it will terminate naturally when it finishes. (I added the 2nd condition when I realized the same thing)

Comment: Also what's everyone's distaste with 'if (++index == 50) break;'. It seems like no one is comfortable with incrementers and decrementers anymore.

Comment: @Orion.  I was going to do that... but the solution is more clear this way. Most new programmers have difficulty with ++index and index++... or wait... is that only in c++?

Answer (score 7):

Use a for loop.

```
for(int index = 0; index < collection.Count && index < 50; index++)
{
   collection[index];
}
```

Comment: This will fail if the collection doesn't have 50 items though.

Comment: This still doesn't work. If it has less than 50 items it doesn't execute at all.

Comment: It will work.  A for loop is nothing but a fancy while loop. (while you have less than the "Count" AND less than 50 (0-49) do the loop.

Answer (score 5):

```
for(int index = 0, limit = Math.Min(50, collection.Count); index < limit; index++)
{
   collection[index];
}
```

Comment: Interesting solution, perhaps not the most clear one though, especially if you don't use the Math library often.

Comment: Interesting, except Math.Min() will be evaluated with each iteration. Better to store this in a local int before the for-loop, and compare the index to that local.

Comment: I'm fairly certain that the compiler is smart enough to optimize that away so that it will only run once.

Comment: Actually my guess is that this would be the fastest of the solutions given that you could determine the limit before running the loop, but it would be such a small number of actual computations, it wouldn't matter.

Comment: @Atomiton: Honestly I think the Min and Max (along with the other math functions) should be in most people's toolboxes. They're pretty fundamental. Additionally this to me seems the most strait-forward. I want to iterate to the smaller number of 50 or the collection size. Then I actually do it.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to still use a foreach loop try the following:

```
int counter = 0;
foreach (ListViewItem lvi in listView.Items) 
{
  counter++;
  if ( counter == 50 )
  {
   break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 50 && i < listView.Items.Count; ++i)
{
    ListViewItem item = listView.Items[i];
}
```

Comment: Probably slightly more efficient to reverse the conditions. Otherwise you'll never take advantage of the && operator's ability to short-circuit.

Comment: @Atomiton - that's assuming that the common case is less than 50 items..  If the average case is 1000 items, then this way is more efficient ;).

Comment: But anyway - it is only more efficient by one comparison. Doesn't really buy you anything in the way of performance.. and not worth worrying about.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a for loop as charles suggested instead of a foreach with an index check.  The intent is more obvious as a for loop is used when you need to keep track of the current iteration.

```
for (int i = 0; i < listView.Items.Count && i < 50; ++i)
{
    //do something with listView.Items[i]
}
```

Comment: Use for (int i = 0; i < listView.Items.Count && i < 50; ++i) to include the < 50 requirement.

Comment: As AaronSieb alluded to, if there are more than 50 items, you won't exit the loop after 50.

Answer (score 1):

```
int i = 50;
foreach(T t in TList)
{
   if(i-- <= 0) break;

   code;

   // or: i--; if(i<=0) break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A for loop will work, but you can still setup a ListViewItem named lvi like so.

```
int maxItems = listViewItems.Count > 50 ? 50 : listViewItems.Count;
for(int counter = 0; counter < maxItems; counter ++)
{ 
    ListViewItem lvi = listView.Items[counter];

    // Rest of your code here will stile work

}
```

Comment: Except that you won't exit the loop after 50 iterations.

Answer (score 1):

Using LINQ, this could be implemented as:

```
foreach (ListViewItem lvi in listView.Items.Take(50))
{
  // do stuff
}
```

Take(n) returns the first n elements or all element if less than n are available.

Answer (score 0):

People have given plenty of examples, and in this specific case since ListView.Items is an indexed collection, an old fashioned for loop is probably best.  If it were something like an IEnumerable where you couldn't use Items[i] then you'd have to do like the other examples with an external counter variable.